# Template function which determines how to move-assign a type

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

In some code that I am writing, I am manipulating some heterogeneous containers of user-defined types.

I desperately need to be able to move-assign these types without generating exceptions.

However, this can cripple the usability of my code because on many older compilers, important standard library types do not have `noexcept` markings on their move-assignment operators. For instance `std::string` appears not to be `noexcept` move-assignable with gcc 4.9, it is only `noexcept` move constructible in C++11.

To work around this, I have developed a template function which tries various strategies for move-assigning things until it finds one which is `noexcept`, if it cannot then it gives up.

```
namespace traits {

template <bool b, typename V = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<b, V>::type;

} // end namespace traits

namespace detail {

template <typename T>
auto move_assign_noexcept(T & dest, T && src) noexcept -> traits::enable_if_t<std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value> {
  dest = std::move(src);
}

template <typename T, typename ENABLE = void>
struct is_nothrow_swappable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_nothrow_swappable<T, traits::enable_if_t<noexcept(std::swap(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr), *static_cast<T*>(nullptr)))>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
auto move_assign_noexcept(T & dest, T && src) noexcept -> traits::enable_if_t<!std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
                                                                   && is_nothrow_swappable<T>::value> {
  std::swap(dest, src);
}

template <typename T>
auto move_assign_noexcept(T & dest, T && src) noexcept -> traits::enable_if_t<!std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
                                                                   && !is_nothrow_swappable<T>::value
                                                                   && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value> {
  dest.~T();
  new (&dest) T(std::move(src));
}

} // end namespace detail
```

This code is supposed to work at C++11 standard.

I recall that there is a standard function `std::move_if_noexcept` which is useful for standard containers which are trying to avoid exception problems.

Is there an existing standard idiom for doing what I am trying to do?

Are there other strategies that I should try? Am I actually using standard traits correctly to ensure that each implementation actually won't throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're putting the cart before the horse here.

> I am manipulating some heterogeneous containers of user-defined types.
>   I desperately need to be able to move-assign these types without generating exceptions.

Let's say your container is a `Cart<T>`. And you need to define a move-assignment operator

```
Cart<T>& Cart<T>::operator=(Cart<T>&& rhs) noexcept;
```

Well, if `Cart` behaves like `std::vector`, then you could implement this as something like

```
Cart<T>& Cart<T>::operator=(Cart<T>&& rhs) noexcept
{
    delete [] this->pointer_to_Ts;
    this->pointer_to_Ts = rhs->pointer_to_Ts;
    rhs->pointer_to_Ts = nullptr;
}
```

Notice that this does *not* require `T`'s own move-assignment operator at all; `T` might not even be movable! The only user-defined function we're executing here is `T`'s *destructor* (and [if that throws, we're in trouble anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506836/what-happens-if-delete-p-fails)).

But okay, let's suppose that you're implementing `Cart`'s move-assignment operator like this instead:

```
Cart<T>& Cart<T>::operator=(Cart<T>&& rhs) noexcept
{
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        this->array_of_Ts[i] = std::move(rhs->array_of_Ts[i]);
    }
}
```

So now you're calling a *ton* of user-defined functions (well, just one function, but you're calling it `n` times). This is already violating the spirit of move-semantics, in that moving is supposed to be a *fast* operation, but we'll let that slide.

What should you do if `T`'s move-assignment operator is defined as `noexcept`? Well, you're golden. Everything will work fine.

What should you do if `T`'s move-assignment operator is *not* defined as `noexcept`, but doesn't throw in practice? Well, you're golden. Everything will work fine in practice. If it ever accidentally *does* throw an exception, then your program will call `std::terminate` and (presumably) exit. This seems like a good idea in most cases. If you really can't afford to call `std::terminate` when something as terrible as "move-assignment throws an exception" happens, then I bet you're coding to some strict government standards that will preclude the existence of non-`noexcept` move-assignment operators in the first place.

What should you do if `T`'s move-assignment operator is explicitly defined as `noexcept(false)`? Well, you should probably go find the person who wrote that code and shoot them in the face. (Politely, of course.)

---

Now the unfortunate bit: It's actually impossible to tell in C++14 (and C++17 as well, AFAIK) whether a given function has been declared `noexcept(false)` or merely non-`noexcept`. So your code won't ever be able to distinguish case 2 above ("you're golden, in practice") from case 3 above ("you have to shoot somebody in the face") — it's useless to try.

So, should you go gray worrying about case 3? IMHO you should not. Just assume that every instance of case-2-or-3 in your codebase is really a case-2; and then write your code accordingly. It'll be simple and straightforward and efficient, and if you ever run into a throwing move-assignment operator, well, by definition it's the *user* who wrote the bad code, not you.

---

This is *not* the philosophy that led to the current [pessimal behavior of `std::vector::resize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows). I'll let someone else take a stab at explaining *that* philosophy, because I don't understand it at all.

Comment: So, unfortunately I can't just move the container, I have a `std::array<T, N>` on my hands and I need to move it. I could send you a link into my actual project I guess.

Comment: The reason I don't want to throw is that, this is supposed to be a lua bindings library, and if the user throws exceptions through lua and catches them on the other side, that's basically a UB. lua is a C library, not exception safe. And it's uniquely tricky because, when you use lua, you are taking C++ functions with signature `int(lua_State *)` and passing those function pointers to the C lib so that it cna call them as callbacks. So the exceptions really will go right through lua's internals.

Comment: I like your idea to just make the function `noexcept` though, I think that is basically correct. I shoudl just tell the user it has to be nothrow move assignable. Even if they are using gcc 4.9 and `std::string` is technically not that, in reality, it is I guess. I would like to make it a static assert so that if they do something stupid they get a message rather than a crash, but that might just be unworkable i guess. There probably aren't any "real" classes that are no throw move contructible and destructible but not no-throw move assignable, so this whole exercise may be silly.

Comment: Note: To clarify: in one case i have a `std::array<T,N>`, in one case, it's some user-defined struct, and I need to default consturct it, and then move values into its fields one by one. In both cases the move assignment is the tricky part. https://github.com/cbeck88/lua-primer/blob/master/include/primer/container/seq_base.hpp#L140  https://github.com/cbeck88/lua-primer/blob/master/include/primer/container/visit_struct.hpp#L110

Comment: Sorry, those links were to "master" and not to a specific commit unfortunately, so the highlighted line has drifted... oh well